# Jackson Json serialization of multiple Hibernate object

Tags: json, hibernate, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have the following code using Hibernate3.

```
List queryResult = session.createQuery("SELECT A, B from A, B where A.id = B.id");
for (Object o: queryResult) {
     Object[] array = (Objec[]) o;
     A a = (A) array[0];
     B b = (B) array[1];
     //do work
}
```

This works fine, as I'm operating directly on the hibernate query results. However, I also want to serialize queryResult to a string, so that I can use it later. I tried the following using Jackson's json library:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper()
final String queryResultString = m.writeValueAsString(queryResult);
```

Then later I try to read and deserialize the string from Json back to Hibernate query result, that's when I hit trouble. The read code:

```
List r = m.readValue(queryResultString, List.class);
for (Object o: r) {
     Object[] array = (Objec[]) o;
     A a = (A) array[0];
     B b = (B) array[1];
     //do work
}
```

The cast of Object[] is complaining about can't cast an ArrayList to an object array.

I tried to use the jackson hibernate module, but that didn't help either. So my questions are: a) what is the right way to do this with JSon serialization? b) why does Jackson deserialize it to arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

When serialized with jackson your list will look similar to:
[[A_item, B_item], [A_item2, B_item2], ... [A_itemn, B_itemn]]
Why? Because you have a list of lists or array of arrays if you prefer (the second list will always have two elements, A and B).

**The problem**

Your list is untyped. So jackson will deseriliaze the json stream to a list of lists.
Because when jackson encounters an array structure and does not know to which type to deserialize it will deserialize to a List and not an array.

**Solution**

1) Instead of using arrays you use lists, as jackson will by default deserialize to a list and not an array (thats why you have the classcast exception).

2) If you are under **java 5+** (this means you can use generics) then you can use jackson TypeReference class.

```
List listOfLists = mapper.readValue(queryResultString, new TypeReference<List<Object[]>>() {});
```

3) You switch from Jackson to Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/ that will by default deserialize to an array and not a list. Genson provides a lot of other nice features that jackson does not have, take a look at the wiki http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted. Genson requires **java 6+**.

```
List r = new Genson().deserialize(queryResultString, List.class);
for (Object o: r) {
 Object[] array = (Objec[]) o;
    // it works!
    A a = (A) array[0];
 }
```

**Edit**
You hava a forEach loop, I conclude that you are under java 6+, then switch to Genson ;)

Comment: 2) doesn't work -- it did pass the Object[] casting statement, but the actual casting of the object (A)array[0] failed with exception: can not cast LinkedHashMap to A. 3) Genson didn't work, as it failed to serialize A.

Comment: 1) your A and B are complex types Jackson does not know by default to what type to deserialize. Thats why he deserialized to a Map. 2) Can you show what your objets look like? I am very surprised that serialization fails...

Comment: A and B are hibernate objects -- i.e., objects returned from querying mysql using hibernate. I thought about serialization might be losing the class info, and tried to add the hibernateModule for object mappper, but it didn't work either.